# Excel data feed with parameters

Tags: excel, odata

Is there any way that I can create a link to a datasource in Excel with includes a parameter for the datasource.

I have written my own OData feed which is working fine and the data's coming into Excel but now I'd like to extend it so that I can pass a parameter up in the server request. Ideally I'd like to take the parameter from a cell in the workbook but if required I can write a VSTO solution which changed the data feed to include the parameter in it - I'd just rather not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the best method is to use Power Query - an MS extension to Excel. This allows you to set up a table with the parameter in it and use that as the parameter for an OData feed.